# Constant Temperature in Conductive Wire

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, temperature, electric-current

I know that when an electric current flows through a conductor, it produces heat. However, while working on some questions, I came across some statements assuming that the temperature is constant. Wouldn't this contradict the fact that there is heat energy produced when a current flows through a wire and hence a change in temperature?

Thank you

Comment: Constant through time, or constant through the wire at a given moment? It doesn't matter anyway, you can always put the wire in a thermal bath if you want, so that its temperature is the same along its length. When there's a current "flowing" through the wire, Joule heat is produced in every single point inside the wire. Depending on the boundary conditions of the wire and on the temperature dependence of the resistance of the wire, this Joule heat might be uneven (but you can make it even if you want), and there might be thermoelectric effects as well, which could modify the temperature acros

Comment: s the wire. So the short answer is that no, there is no contradiction in assuming that the temperature across a wire is constant throughout, be it in time or at a given time, despite the possible several heats produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temperature increases and energy flows to the neighborhood. While the power dissipated in the resistance is greater than this heat flow rate, the temperature keeps rising.

Once an equilibium is reached, the temperature remains constant. It is the case of an incandescent lamp. The resistive electric power equals the energy per unit of time emitted as EM waves.

But a fuse is based exactly in the principle that an excessive power increases its temperature until the melting point. No equilibrium in this case.